AWS EC2 for database update with python
I have python flask app which is desinged to write/insert rows and update db in SQL Server. I am interested in followings:
If I deploy flask app on Ec2 instance, do I still need to install sql server on EC2 instance as well, or current setup of flask will handle database connections and EC2 instance will not end up with connection issue (of course I need to modify inbound security roles to add custom TCP for flask and sql server)? If yes, If i turn off my laptop and run app on EC2 continously, will there be any interreptions (e.g. transaction rollback, connection timeout)?
Thanks in advance!

Flask by itself does not handle database connections, are you speaking about Flask-SQLAlchemy extension, or some other database driver/package?

What role does your laptop play in this scenario?

I know flask doesn’t handle db connections. Just I use flask and html for UI to start database update.

I just would like to learn if python IDE project is designed to build connection to database and running queries/procedures in sql server, does Ec2 instance needs to be modified by installing sql server or do I need to use AWS RDS service to create new db?

Flask doesn't include SQL Server, or any database server in fact. If you're determined to use SQL Server specifically, as opposed to another DB like PostgreSQL or even SQLite, then you can install SQL Server on EC2. Or you could use RDS to deploy SQL Server. Installing and running SQL Server on the same EC2 instance as your Flask app isn't ideal, and should certainly not be done for any production-like workload, but it might be acceptable for a small test environment.

I meant to say rest API actually. I just use it for UI. Backend is built on sql queries. But if i want to run update (which takes 7-8 hours) continously; without dependent on local sql server, do I need to migrate db into AWS RDS? I think if I turn off my laptop, ec2 instance will lose connection to db?

Why do you think that your laptop has anything to do with the EC2 instance? Is the database running on your laptop?

it runs in server but if i turn off my laptop, connection will be lost. That’s why my idea is to use ec2
